# How can I Remove Question Mark and Change Name From URL?

Tags: .htaccess

i'm trying to remove **?** from the URL currently url is showing as

```
http://www.tenantfind.co.uk/blog-detail.php?id=4
```

and it should open as

```
http://www.tenantfind.co.uk/blog/new-legal-helpline
```

i tried the following solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(blog-detail)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog-detail?$1 [L]
```

but it is redirecting to following link and showing blank page, no data on page

```
http://www.tenantfind.co.uk/blog-detail
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(?:blog-detail)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/?$ /blog-detail?$1 [L]
```

Comment: URL is exactly the same as I want but it is not displaying any page and showing **Internal Server Error**

Comment: Without htaccess, your link `http://www.tenantfind.co.uk/blog-detail?Full-management-services` worked ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Croises yup it's working fine without adding this code in .htaccess file... you can check live link

Comment: @Croises i just update it and update my question also, you can see now

Comment: Yes, but you can not change the subject and hoped that the answers will continue to work. Without me, because what you ask now is not possible only with .htaccess.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained